# How to sort data in firebase realtime database?

Tags: javascript, react-native, firebase-realtime-database

I'm really struggling to figure out how to get data sorted in the real-time database. I keep referring to their documentation and applying the steps as described, but it seems like nothing is happening in terms of sorting data. I believe it should work the same as filtering, which is working fine, but no positive result.

Here is my code [React Native]:

```
useEffect(() => {
    onValue(
      // Order by the "createAt" field
      query(
        ref(db, "deals/"),
        orderByChild("createAt"),
        startAt("2023-12-31 23:59:59")
      ),
      (snapshot) => {
        setData(snapshot.val());
      },
      (err) => {
        console.error(err);
      }
    );
}, []);
```

I've also tried applying other sorting functions, such as orderByChild(), orderByKey(), and orderByValue(). Additionally, I attempted to change the field to both 'number' and 'string' types, but still haven't found a solution that works.

Answer (score 0):

First off: you have a typo in `createAt` (it's missing a `d` after `create`), so make sure that's actually what the property is called in the database.

If that matches, the database will actually return a snapshot that has the child nodes in the right order. But your code then calls `snapshot.val()`, which converts the data into a JSON object - and child nodes in JSON are by definition unordered.

To fix this, use the built-in `forEach` operation of the snapshot to process the child nodes in order - and pass then to your UI as an array:

```
(snapshot) => {
  let results = [];
  snapshot.forEach((child) => { 
    results.push({ 
      id: child.key,
      ...child.val()
    ); 
  }
  setData(results);
},
```

You'll of course also have to update the code that renders the UI to handle the array.

Comment: For the property, it was originally named 'startDate,' but I changed it to make it clearer. Now, I realize that there is no straightforward way to retrieve sorted data. The challenge with sorting on the frontend is that I can't fetch all the records to sort them, as it would take too long.

I initially thought that one of the following methods might solve the issue: orderByChild(), orderByKey(), or orderByValue(). However, it seems like none of these options will work.

Thank you for your assistance

Comment: "Now, I realize that there is no straightforward way to retrieve sorted data" I'm not sure I follow, as that is *exactly* what the code in my answer does: it traverses the results in the order that the server returns them in. Did you try to run the code from my answer?